# Search bar won´t accept close button

Tags: html, css, searchbar

I have this search bar, but whatever I do I can´t seem to be able to add the little grey/black "x" to clear the text in the search bar. Would love some help with this. Thanks alot!

```css
input[type=search] {
    width: 130px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 2px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 4px;
    font-size: 14px;
    background-color: white;
    background-image: url('searchicon.png');
    background-position: 10px 10px; 
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px;
    -webkit-transition: width 0.4s ease-in-out;
    transition: width 0.4s ease-in-out;
    position: absolute;
    right: 10px;
    top: 3px;
}

input[type=search]:focus  {
    width: 25%;
    
}
```

```html
<input type="search" id="myInput" placeholder="Search..">
```

Comment: It seems to work fine.

Comment: Here it works yeah. But I have this bootstrap: <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

And while using this it dont work..

Comment: Since it works here, try to call the style AFTER you call bootstrap style.

Comment: I found a solution for it! Thanks anyways! :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had problems using the bootstrap with the "x". However, I used this CSS and it worked perfectly!

```css
input[type=search] {
    width: 130px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 2px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 4px;
    font-size: 14px;
    background-color: white;
    background-image: url('searchicon.png');
    background-position: 10px 10px; 
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px;
    -webkit-transition: width 0.4s ease-in-out;
    transition: width 0.4s ease-in-out;
    position: absolute;
    right: 10px;
    top: 3px;
}

input[type=search]:focus  {
    width: 25%;
    
}
```

```html
<input type="search" id="myInput" placeholder="Search..">
```

```css
input[type="search"] {
 -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
 -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
 box-sizing: content-box;
 -webkit-appearance: searchfield;
}

input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-cancel-button {
-webkit-appearance: searchfield-cancel-button;
}
```